# How do you embed a google drive form in a Jquery mobile app?

Tags: jquery-mobile, google-drive-api, google-forms

I've tried embedding as an iframe but when I press the submit button it greys out and does not submit the google drive form.

Answer (score 0):

I had the iframe in a control group

```
<div data-role="controlgroup">
```

div, but when I removed this it worked.